# Function ess. bounded and its property

Tags: functional-analysis

I considered some inequality and I don't know if my assumption was true.

Let $a$ be essential bounded function, so $||a||_{\infty}=C < \infty$ and $a \neq 0$ a.e.

Is the truth that $\frac{1}{a}$ is essential bounded a.e.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a(x) = 1/x$ on $\{ x \in \mathbb R \;|\; x \ge 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$. Bounded by 1, 0 nowhere, so in particular essentially bounded by 1 and non-zero a.e. But $1/(1/x)=x$ which diverges and is definitely not essentially bounded.

Comment: You beat my by 4 seconds ;)

Comment: Ha, the exact same answer. Nice!

Comment: Maybe it is the only counterexample... ;)

Comment: Just as I thought. Thanks both of you.